# Nothing in my Xcode project is editable?

Tags: ios, xcode, file, viewcontroller, locked

I just recently finished my project and I was chaining a few things and them suddenly nothing is changing when I run it on simulator or device. It stays the same. When I change the text on label it stays same. Nothing is changing at all! Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer or cleaning the build. There are times xcode gets buggy and just stops functioning properly.

Comment: Sorry extremely new how to clean the build? Thanks if this works you're the best.

Comment: It should be on the upper navigation and under build or ⇧ + ⌘ + K

Comment: Thanks it worked! Please Write your answer as a proper answer so I can tick you and you can get rep. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to know I can help. It's inspiring to hear young coders like you. Don't give up!!!

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know there a professionals like you willing to help young coders like my self! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried restarting your computer or cleaning the build. There are times xcode gets buggy and just stops functioning properly.

Comment: 4 minutes and ill tick it!